# Autocomplete User defined Functions for notepad++?

Tags: php, autocomplete, dreamweaver, notepad++, text-editor

dreamweaver has an option to automatically scan a directory and index all the user defined functions so you can then easily reference and auto complete when writing code. I am using notepad++ to right PHP and would like a similar feature without the need of manually updating an API or config file or anything for notepad++.

Does anyone know of a plugin/addon etc or maybe a better open source program which allows this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/)? It's a really cool text editor, that implements natively what are you asking for.

Comment: It looks nice, but it's not free/open source.

Comment: Actually it's free. You don't have to buy the license. It works same as winrar does: periodically it will ask you to buy it, but it will never force you.

Comment: So it does, i'm giving it a try, seeing if i can find the user defined function compeltion bit.

Comment: I'm using it for a year, and actually I think it's the best free one ;)

Comment: I don't really see a way to provide a directory/project folder which it scans for user defined functions to use. I'm not nessarily going to have already used them. For example, I may way to reference a function in an included file.

Comment: For example I've used it with Elgg, and it was recognizing Elgg's function, helping me with the autocomplete function. Some standard autocomplete functions are added depending on the file extension. You can also add some autocomplete by yourself if you need to.

Comment: hm, i'm kind of looking for something that will index my included functions automatically and give me hits for their paremeters.

Comment: Sublime Text 2 only natively autocompletes text within the current file. http://urbangiraffe.com/2011/08/15/sublime-text-2-for-php/ is a nice starter which includes information on some plugins that attempt to bring IDE style functionality into a great text editor. Just as a warning though, I have seen problems reported using the _Sublime Lint_ plugin mentioned in the article.